# Cannot find reference assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I'm use Visual Studio Enterprise Version 17.2.6 and sdk NET 6
when use Calss libray in web project and publish on IIS  SEE THIS ERROR  :`Cannot find reference assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll' file for package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery`

i include the package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation"` ver 6.0.7

when run project debug vs dont show error (iis express)

Cannot find reference assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll' file for package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery

Comment: [Does this github issue useful to u ?](https://github.com/toddams/RazorLight/issues/294#issuecomment-566147337)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you run command Ex. "dotnet publish -f netcoreapp2.1 -c Release" so you get a folder (bin\publish) which contains all files you need to run your application.
Also, make sure you've configured your .csproj file to include your 3rd party packages.